# How to use Django -avatar in an existing django project, any documentation or example?

Tags: django, avatar

I am new to django and having hard time implementing django-avatar in my user registration. My user signup is having big trouble(cross browser issues) implementing profile photo upload. So I want to use standard plugin like django -avatar but is there any good documentation/implementation example apart from [this](https://github.com/jezdez/django-avatar)? If not is there any other plugin with good documentation or resource for photo upload by users which is stable across all browsers?

Comment: That documentation looks pretty good to me.

Comment: For a beginner like me, it does not tell on 1)how to use it in signup forms(which I figured it out with another post) 2)how to use the urls for each user etc. Might be documents like those are not targeted at beginners! Is django-avatar designed for site integration in particular? Is there any other plugin addressing the user profile picture uploading?